# Select array elements that are greater than 5% of a sum

Tags: ruby

```
sum = @products.inject(0){ |sum,item| sum += item['count'] }
@selected = @products.select { |item| (item['count']/sum) >= 0.05 }
```

I want to select every element from the `@products` array whose `count` property is greater than 5% of the `sum`. `@products` is an array of hashes.

However, when I use this second line, @selected returns an empty array. After finding no fault with `|item|` or the `@products` array itself, I'm inclined to believe it has something to do with trying to use an external variable, `sum`, inside the `.select` block. Could someone explain to me why `@selected` is returning nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `count`s are integers, `item['count']/sum` will always be zero due to integer division.

Try the following instead:

```
@selected = @products.select { |item| item['count'] >= 0.05 * sum }
```

Answer (score 3):

Write as below :

```
 @selected = @products.select { |item| (item['count'].to_f/sum) >= 0.05 }
```

You need to make either `item['count']` or `sum` as floating point number to get floating point number,after the division. Quick example  to prove my words in **PRY**

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> 12/13
=> 0
>> 12/13.to_f
=> 0.9230769230769231
>> 12.to_f/13
=> 0.9230769230769231
>>
```

Comment: Blah, you both had great answers! Thank you!